# Indexing Ops in TF

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

Is there a way to index an operation in tensorflow? In particular, I'm interested in indexing by the iterator variable of `tf.while_loop`.

More concretely, let's say I have `my_ops = [op1, op2]`. I would like to have:

```
my_ops = [...]
i = tf.constant(0)
c = lambda i: tf.less(i, 10)
b = lambda i: my_ops[i](...)
r = tf.while_loop(c, b, [i])
```

which unfortunately will not work, since a python array supports only integer indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is not possible. However, you could instead use [tf.stack](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack) to stack the operations' output tensors, and then use [tf.gather](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather) to obtain the desired output.

Here you have an example:

```
import tensorflow as tf


def condition(i, x):
    return tf.less(i, 10)


def body_1(my_ops):
    def b(i, x):
        stacked_results = tf.stack([op(x) for op in my_ops])
        gather_idx = tf.mod(i, 2)
        return [i + 1, tf.gather(stacked_results, gather_idx)]

    return b


def body_2(my_ops):
    def b(i, x):
        nb_ops = len(my_ops)
        pred_fn_pairs = [(tf.equal(tf.mod(i, nb_ops), 0), lambda: my_ops[0](x)),
                         (tf.equal(tf.mod(i, nb_ops), 1), lambda: my_ops[1](x))]
        result = tf.case(pred_fn_pairs)
        return [i + 1, result]

    return b


my_ops = [lambda x: tf.Print(x + 1, [x, 1]),
          lambda x: tf.Print(x + 2, [x, 2])]
i = tf.constant(0)
x = tf.constant(0)
r = tf.while_loop(condition, body_2(my_ops), [i, x])  # See the difference with body_1

with tf.Session() as sess:
    i, x = sess.run(r)
    print(x)  # Prints 15 = 5*2 + 5*1
```

Comment: Nice! I wonder how much runtime overhead this causes, if at all. Do you think tf will figure to actually compute only the corresponding op at i'th iteration?

Comment: No, this will compute every operation at the i-th iteration (I added [tf.Print](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Print) to check this). You might find `body_2` more useful (it uses [tf.case](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/case) to compute only the corresponding operation).